# Equivalent of Guavas Maps.uniqueIndex(...) for Set

Tags: java, collections, guava

Guava has a static method `Maps.uniqueIndex(Iterable<V> values, Function<? super V,K> keyFunction)` which maps each entry in the entered collection by the result of the entered function applied on respective elements.

Is there an equivalent of this function for Sets (where the return value is not a map but a set)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a straight-forward solution:

```
FluentIterable.from(values).transform(keyFunction).toSet();
```

Answer (score 3):

A few alternatives:

```
Maps.uniqueIndex(values, keyFunction).keySet();
ImmutableSet.copyOf(Collections2.transform(values, function));
```

Comment: I had these two approaches in mind but it seems a little ineffective to create a map just to get it's key set (1. solution), or to create an unknown collection and then the actual set as it's copy (2. solution). Too bad Guava doesn't support this.

Comment: @Jardo: don't forget that the transformed collection is not a copy, but a live view over the original collection.

Comment: Jardo: Collections.transform returns an O(1) view; it's not expensive.  (And sets aren't actually cheaper than maps due to padding; they just don't maintain references to the value objects.)

Comment: You're right, I guess it's not a bad solution after all.